# Error MSB4018 The "GenerateClsidMap" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop

I am trying to make a class available for Com Interop in Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.10.1). The project is created in .Net 5. During the build I get the error message 'Error MSB4018 The "GenerateClsidMap" task failed unexpectedly'.

I have the following settings:
Controller.csproj:

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>
    <EnableRegFreeCom>true</EnableRegFreeCom>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

WindowController.cs

```
[Guid("D2B2F7DB-XXXX-XXXX-B015-A0970C3716CB")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("XXX.Controller.WindowController")]
public class WindowController : IWindowController
```

IWindowControler.cs

```
[Guid("5EACF76F-XXXX-XXXX-9296-12BE41A02D5B")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IWindowController
{
    [DispId(10)]
    string NameParameter { get; set; }
    [DispId(20)]
    int NrParameter { get; set; }
```

While searching for a solution I found the following sample project:
https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/extensions/COMServerDemo

When I compile this, the same error occurs.

Does anyone know the problem or can reproduce it? Is there a solution for it?

Edit: Here is the output when compiling

```
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(537,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateClsidMap" task failed unexpectedly.
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(537,5): error MSB4018: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.NET.HostModel.ComHost.ClsidMap.Create(System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReader, System.String)'.
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(537,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateClsidMap.ExecuteCore()
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(537,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(537,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskWithAssemblyResolveHooks.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(537,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(537,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Comment: I have no problem compiling your project or the sample one with Visual Studio 2019 16.1.0.1. You could try a VS repair.

Comment: Since it can be reproduced on my colleague (VS 2019 16.10.0), I can't imagine it's my installation of VS. How can you open a .Net Core 3.1 project (e.g. the ComServer from the link above) with your 16.1.0.1? I thought you needed at least 16.4 for that?

Comment: Correction: It should read GenerateClsidMap instead of GeneratedClsidMap

Comment: sorry was a typo, I meant 16.10.1, same as you (and also with latest 16.10.2). Or post your full project files somewhere.

Comment: Hi Simon, thought you probably meant the 16.10. I have now tried to repair VS 2019 --> without success. I first removed various extensions and then completely removed VS and reinstalled it --> error still occurs. I also changed various things in the project, all without success. But now I have installed VS on a PC that is not used for development. I can compile without errors. My colleague and I must have something on the computer that triggers this error. In the meantime, I am completely at a loss and have no idea what else to do.

Comment: You can try to change msbuild output verbosity to detailed or diagnostics https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFWAK.png see if it tells anything more; Also compare the list of installed components in VS Installer, with the PC where it works.

Comment: The output is too long for a commentary. I have edited my post instead.

Comment: "Method not found" is typically a deployment/setup issue. The referencing component (GenerateClsidMap class in Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.dll in a path something like C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\tools\net5.0) was compiled against a referenced component and uses some methods. Once deployed and executed in certain configuration and context, this referencing component doesn't find the method it was compiled against. Maybe try to repair .NET Core, or uninstall / reinstall...

Comment: How does it work? I removed and reinstalled Visual Studio three times today. Is this a separate package?

Comment: Not sure. Visual Studio is a vehicle for .NET but I guess you can try by this route too https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0 or, after you uninstall VS, uninstall .NET, then reinstall everything... Type `dotnet --info` to check where all that is and make sure it's gone or removed when you think it is. There's also a msbuild that comes with .NET, maybe that's the issue `dotnet msbuild`

Comment: Hi Simon, first of all, thank you very much. I'm on holiday this week and won't be able to check it until next week. I will give you feedback then. But I suspect an extension that may have changed something in .Net.

Answer (score 0):

First I removed Visual Studio and all installations of .Net Core and .Net 5 and reinstalled Visual Studio. Then I could sometimes compile the ComServerDemo project, then it didn't work again. After much further searching I found the following:
[Add support for COMReference items on .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/3986)
[COM activation for .NET Core on Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/COM-activation.md)

Compiling ComServerDemo works if you do it via the Developer-PowerShell (dotent build). With my own project, I also have the problem that I reference a Com component in it again. That doesn't seem to work with .Net 5 yet. Here I get the following message:

> MSB4803: The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of MSBuild.

It also refers to the page [ResolveComReference task](https://aka.ms/msbuild/MSB4803). It says that you should not use the normal command line for compiling, but the Developer command line. But I get this error anyway.

We have now decided to do this with .Net Framework 4.8 for the time being and only migrate to .Net 5, 6, 7 when the Com stories run reliably there.

Many thanks to Simon Mourier for his patient support!